# export QTableWidget as pdf with PyQt5/6

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt5, qtablewidget, pyqt6

i made a QTableWidget with data and an export to pdf button, i made a function, and it makes a download and puts a pdf file in selected folder, but the file will not open.

this is my code

```
import test

class recordsWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, record_list=None):
        super().__init__()
         ....  
    

        # present records chart
        record_list = test.show_records(self)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Blod Type", "Donation Date", "First Name", "Last Name", "ID"])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 125)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 125)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 125)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 125)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4,125)

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(record_list))

        i=0
        for record in record_list:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem((record[0])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem((record[1])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem((record[2])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 3, QTableWidgetItem((record[3])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 4, QTableWidgetItem((record[4])))
            i+=1

        # activate export
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.exportPDF)


    def exportPDF(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Export PDF", "", "PDF files (*.pdf)")
        if filename:
            printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution)
            printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.OutputFormat.PdfFormat)
            printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
            printer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4))

            try:
                painter = QPainter()
                painter.begin(printer)

                # render the table into the painter object
                self.tableWidget.render(painter)

                painter.end()
                print("PDF generated successfully")
            except Exception as e:
                print("PDF generation failed: ", e)
```

which not actually makes a vlid file.also not getting any exception or error.